# Get all TI Indicators returns an empty list

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-sentinel

I am trying to collect all active TIs via the Beta Graph API by following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/tiindicators-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http). But it doesn't return anything. Here is what I use in Postman:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/security/tiIndicators`

Response (200):

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#security/tiIndicators",
    "value": []
}
```

A bit of context for the environment I work in.

- The tenant has multiple Sentinel workspaces & resource groups.
- The application I use has the correct permissions:

  - `ThreatIndicators.Read.All`
  - `ThreatIndicators.ReadWrite.OwnedBy`
  - `ThreatSubmission.Read.All`
  - `ThreatSubmission.ReadWrite.All`

It is my current belief that this might be due to the limitations of the Beta API. My reasoning is that accourding to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/tiindicators-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) documentation you need the `ThreatIndicators.ReadWrite.OwnedBy` permission to access the API. This would suggest that currently you can only view TI's that the resource itself created.

If more info is needed just ask.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference?context=graph%2Fapi%2Fbeta&view=graph-rest-beta#delegated-permissions-61), `ThreatIndicators.ReadWrite.OwnedBy` permission allow you to manage threat indicators your app creates or owns.

If you want to read all the threat indicators for your organization then your app needs `ThreatIndicators.Read.All` permission.

Comment: I have added that permmission and still nothing. Altough I have found something interesting. We also have a different service principle that adds TI information to the TI instance and when I use that service principle it works. It has the `ThreatSubmission.ReadWrite.All` permission.

Comment: @Rubeste That's interesting

Comment: As of Now I still can not access any TI's. My current belief is that it can only show TI's that the service principle made. According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/tiindicators-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) the `ThreatIndicators.ReadWrite.OwnedBy` permissions are needed to call the API. I think this suggests that currently it is not possible to get TI's made by other TI sources.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not a solution to the question it is a workaround. By using the [Log Analytics API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/api/request-format#post-query) you can get the TI via a KQL.

```
ThreatIntelligenceIndicator
| where ExpirationDateTime > now() and 
    NetworkIP matches regex @"^(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9]|)\d)\.?\b){4}$" and 
    ConfidenceScore > 25
| summarize by NetworkIP
```

This is probably better as you can also use a watchlist to exclude specific IP addresses with one request.

One thing I struggled with this was Authorization. You must give your Application permission to use the `api.loganalytics.io` API, and the application needs the `Log Analytics Reader` role in the Log Analytic workspace you want to use.